# Why am I getting a "not declared in scope" error in the declaration itself?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the << operator for cout and my custom linked list class. However, I'm getting the error "ptr was not declared in this scope" on the line of the actual declaration itself in the very last method in LinkedList.hpp (`LinkedList<T>::Node* ptr = list.getHead();`). Am I missing something?

Here's the code:

```
// LinkedList.hpp

#ifndef LINKED_LIST_HPP
#define LINKED_LIST_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
    public:
        class Node {
            private:
                T _data;
                Node* _next;
            public:
                Node(T data);
                T getData();
                Node* getNext();
        };
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();
        int size();
        LinkedList<T>::Node* getHead();
    private:
        LinkedList<T>::Node* _head;
        int _size;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, LinkedList<T>& list);

#include "LinkedList.cpp"
#endif



// LinkedList.cpp

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T data) {
    _data = data;
    _next = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Node::getData() {
    return _data;
}

template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::Node::getNext() {
    return _next;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    _head = nullptr;
    _tail = nullptr;
    _size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    Node* ptr = _head;
    while (ptr != nullptr) {
        _head = _head->getNext();
        delete ptr;
        ptr = _head;
    }
}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::size() {
    return _size;
}

template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::getHead() {
    return _head;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, LinkedList<T>& list) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        o << "NULL";
    }
    else {
        LinkedList<T>::Node* ptr = list.getHead();
        while (ptr->getNext() != nullptr) {
            o << ptr->getData() << " -> ";
        }
        o << ptr->getData();
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: @tstrickler Please present your [MCVE].

Comment: My guess: you're trying to access `LinkedList<T>::Node` which is a dependent type, so the declaration is ill-formed. Try using `typename LinkedList<T>::Node* ptr = ...` instead.

Comment: `auto ptr = list.getHead();` ftw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue that `Node` is a dependent type, and so you need to do this:

```
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* ptr = list.getHead();
```

See this answer for more details on when this is necessary and why: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/975989)

Comment: You're probably right, though it would be better to train people to provide fully-featured questions before we answer them!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's true, what is the etiquette on doing this right now? As in should I remove the answer or do something else?

Comment: Dunno, it's probably fine, just putting a thought out there